# Create Extent to use in mapView.goto

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, web-mapping, extents, mapping

I would like to use the `goTo()` method of the mapview, and pass it an Extent that I construct in the code.
I created the extent by:

```
const extent = new Esri.Extent({
    xmax: maxX,
    xmin: minX,
    ymax: maxY
    ymin: minY,
    spatialReference: { wkid: 4326 },
});
```

And then:

```
mapView.goTo(extent);
```

And nothing happens...
When I used the goTo with an Extent I got from `locator.addressToLocations` it did work.